# Does Ruby's attr_accessor automatically create instance variables for attributes?

Tags: ruby

For example, if we write

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :something
end
```

but did not explicitly create an initialize method with instance variable `@something`, does Ruby automatically create it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. Instance variables are not defined until you assign to them, and `attr_accessor` doesn't do so automatically.

Attempting to access an undefined instance variable returns `nil`, but *doesn't define that variable*. They don't actually get defined until you *write* to them. `attr_accessor` relies on this behaviour and doesn't do anything except define a getter/setter.

You can verify this by checking out `.instance_variables`:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :something
end
```

A new instance of `x` has no instance variables:

```
x = Test.new # => #<Test:0xb775314c>
x.instance_variables # => []
```

Invoking the getter does not cause `@something` to become defined:

```
x.something # => nil
x.instance_variables # => []
```

Invoking the setter *does* cause `@something` to become defined:

```
x.something = 3 # => 3
x.instance_variables # => ["@something"]
```

Setting `something` back to `nil` doesn't cause `instance_variables` to revert, so we can be sure that the first empty array returned isn't simply a case of `instance_variables` omitting `nil` values:

```
x.something = nil # => nil
x.instance_variables # => ["@something"]
```

You can also verify that this isn't simply behaviour specific to `attr_accessor`:

```
class Test
  def my_method

    @x # nil

    instance_variables # []

    @x = 3 

    instance_variables # ["@x"]
  end 
end

Test.new.my_method
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. In Ruby, instance variables are created when they are first assigned. This is completely transparent to the programmer. They default to nil until assigned.

Ex:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def baz
    @nonexistant
  end
end
f.bar #=> nil
f.baz #=> nil
f.bar = 4
f.bar #=> 4
```

Until you assign a value to an instance variable, it floats in a undefined nil state.